Embedding Riemannian manifold into Euclidean space with matching distances
Let $(\mathcal{M},g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $d$ the induced shortest path distance. I am interested in deciding whether there exists an embedding $\iota:\mathcal{M}\to \mathbb{R}^M$, with $M$ not necessarily related to the dimension of the manifold $\mathcal{M}$, such that
$$d(x,y)=||\iota(X)-\iota(y)||_2, \quad \forall x,y\in \mathcal{M}.$$
In the literature, I could not really find an answer to my question: On the one hand, the Nash embedding theorem guarantees that each Riemannian manifold can be isometrically embedded into some $\mathbb{R}^M.$ However, in my understanding this means that
$$d(x,y)=\text{dist}(\iota(x),\iota(y)),$$
where $\text{dist}$ denotes the path distance induced on the embedded submanifold $\iota(\mathcal{M})$ by using the Euclidean scalar product as Riemannian metric on $\iota(\mathcal{M}).$ This is not what I am looking for.
On the other hand, I have seen in Lee's Riemannian manifolds book that a Riemannian manifold is locally isometric to Euclidean space, iff the curvature tensor vanishes. However, this is also not exactly what I am looking for, because in my understanding this deals with the situation, where $M=\text{dim}(\mathcal{M}).$ In this situation, it answers my question (the necessary and sufficient condition is then just that the curvature tensor of $(M,g)$ is $0$), however, I can not see why such an embedding should not exist for a higher dimensional $\mathbb{R}^M$.
Is my understanding of the two results correct? An if so, are there any results about my original question?

Not quite a duplicate, but possibly of interest as a complement to Mikhail's (+1) answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4086673/two-metrics-on-mathbb-pn-mathbb-c

The kind of embedding you are looking for is sometimes called strongly isometric.  For example, any compact Riemannian manifold admits a strongly isometric embedding into the space $L^\infty(M)$ endowed with the sup-norm.  This embedding is fairly "canonical" and sends a point $x\in M$ to the distance function $d_x$ from $x$.
Now $L^\infty(M)$ is of course not a Hilbert space.  It turns out that there are essentially never any strongly isometric embeddings into a Hilbert space, not even for a Riemannian circle.  Indeed, if the embedding were to be strongly isometric, an arc of the circle would have to embed as a straight line segment.  This is clearly impossible to do globally for $S^1$.

I would have guessed that the required condition by OP would imply that the embedding is totally geodesic. I never encountered the term "strongly isometric", is there a fundamental difference?

@Didier, to talk of geodesics you need to be in a Riemannian manifold.  The notion of strongly isometric embedding is broader and can be used in the context of the embedding I mentioned (sometimes called the Kuratowski embedding (a term I introduced)).  I can link a few papers using the term if you are interested.

Right I see, so it is a notion extending that of totally geodesic embedding in the more general setting of normed vector spaces / metric spaces, isn't it? It would be very nice of you to provide such references, thanks!

@Didier, just look for "Kuratowski embedding".  If that doesn't help, let me know.

One can be more precise: Such an embedding  (of a Riemannian manifold $M$) in a Hilbert space exists if and only if the manifold is isometric to an open convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$, where $n$ is the dimension of $M$.

Thanks a lot for all your quick and insightful comments! I have two small follow-ups: 1. @MoisheKohan Do you have a source for this statement or is this somehow easy to see?
2. What about the situation, when I do not want a global embedding, but need only local ones. Again the Lee results in my question would say that for $M=\text{dim}(M)$ this only works if curvature is $0$. Can one say something for bigger $M$?

@user500357: It is an easy exercise. Increasing dimension makes no difference (I even mentioned a Hilbert space, which could be infinite-dimensional).
